# self-referential has_many trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, self-join

I getting troubles with a self referential table.

I got an orb model which can hold planets, stars and moons. I want to tell that one thing "orbit" another

i look at the rails guide, but i coulnd get it working

My model:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orb_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books

  belongs_to :orbit, :class_name => "Orb"
  has_many :orbs, :class_name => "Orb", :foreign_key => "orb_id"

  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :orb_type_id, :book_ids, :orb_id

  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

I think i am using bad relations names (maybe in the wrong way around)

```
1.9.3-p448 :002 > earth = Orb.find(1)
  Orb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Orb id: 1, nome: "Terra", descr: "123123", orb_type_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:35", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:57:40", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :003 > moon = Orb.find(2)
  Orb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Orb id: 2, nome: "Lua", descr: "asd", orb_type_id: 2, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:46", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:55:31", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :004 > sun = Orb.find(3)
  Orb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 => #<Orb id: 3, nome: "Sol", descr: "asd", orb_type_id: 3, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :006 > moon.orbit=earth
 => #<Orb id: 1, nome: "Terra", descr: "123123", orb_type_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:35", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:57:40", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :007 > earth.orbit=sun
 => #<Orb id: 3, nome: "Sol", descr: "asd", orb_type_id: 3, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :008 > earth
 => #<Orb id: 1, nome: "Terra", descr: "123123", orb_type_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:35", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:57:40", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :009 > sun
 => #<Orb id: 3, nome: "Sol", descr: "asd", orb_type_id: 3, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:55", orb_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p448 :010 > moon
 => #<Orb id: 2, nome: "Lua", descr: "asd", orb_type_id: 2, created_at: "2013-09-25 14:53:46", updated_at: "2013-09-25 14:55:31", orb_id: nil>
```

in the end nothing get associated, the FK still nill.

The collun orb_id was added latter on the model. I setup a migration and added it in the model. I don't think it could be related to my problem...

---

**EDIT:**

Now everything is even odd. i change my model to:

```
class Orb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orb_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books

  belongs_to :orbit, :class_name => "Orb"
  has_many :orbits, :class_name => "Orb", :foreign_key => "orb_id"

  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :orb_type_id, :book_ids, :orb_id

  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

In rails console (rails c) i try:

```
1.9.3-p448 :008 > earth = Orb.find(1)
  Orb Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Orb id: 1, nome: "Terra", descr: "", orb_type_id: 1, created_at: "2013-09-25 17:51:26", updated_at: "2013-09-25 18:16:58", orb_id: 3> 
1.9.3-p448 :009 > earth.orbit
 => nil 
1.9.3-p448 :010 > earth.orbits
  Orb Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."orb_id" = 1
 => [#<Orb id: 2, nome: "Lua", descr: "", orb_type_id: 2, created_at: "2013-09-25 17:51:40", updated_at: "2013-09-25 18:17:31", orb_id: 1>] 
1.9.3-p448 :011 >
```

What the heck? orbits seen to return what i want, but it i try to use it:

```
1.9.3-p448 :004 > earth.orbits.nome
NoMethodError:   Orb Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "orbs".* FROM "orbs" WHERE "orbs"."orb_id" = 1
undefined method `nome' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003d593c0>
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:100:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):4
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out. I should make the rom in the table withe the name of relation (orbit_id) instead of doing it the table name (orb_id)

Fixing that everything started to work nicely :)

```
has_many :orbters, class_name: "Orb", foreign_key: "orbit_id"
belongs_to :orbit, class_name: "Orb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's not great that you have planets, stars, and moons all within the same model.  They all behave differently and should each warrant their own model.  E.g. a star will never orbit a planet, and a planet will never orbit a moon (by definition).  By structuring your database the way you have, you're setting yourself up for corrupted data, which will always happen if you allow it to.

If you must have them all within the `Orb` model, I would recommend 2 models: 1 for the `Orbs` (stars, planets, moons), and 1 for the `Orbits`. The `Orbit` class would essentially be a table like so:

```
Orbit model:

| id | orbited_id | orbiter_id |
--------------------------------
|  0 | planet_id  | moon_id    |
|  1 | star_id    | planet_id  |
|  2 | planet_id  | moon_id    |
| ...| etc        | etc        |
```

And then you can set up the association in orb.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :orbits,
                        class_name: 'Orb',
                        join_table: :orbits,
                        foreign_key: :orbited_id,
                        association_foreign_key: :orbiter_id,
                        uniq: true
```

This will allow you to do things like

```
>> sun = Orb.find(1)
>> sun.orbits
=> [ <Orb mercury>, <Orb venus>, ..., <Orb pluto> ]
```

Comment: I know that i could have a table for each kind of type, but i have the association of orb_type because i need more than just those 3 types (an asteroid filed an so on...) The reason that i am wanting put an self reference here is because this table already can hold all the data i want, and i dont mind in if the relation meaning could be odd (a star orbiting a moon, for exemple)

Comment: Got it.  You should still use my above suggestion and eliminate the `OrbType` model.  Instead, you can track `orb_type` as a column on the `Orb` model and then just get all asteroids by doing `Orb.where(orb_type: 'asteroid')`, etc

Comment: But then i would have to hardcode all the types when inserting a new orb ;p

Comment: Anyway, the orb_type -> orb relation works fine and is unrelated to the thing i am trying to solve. My problem is with orb->orb relation

Comment: OK, still not the route I would go for `orb_type` as it is more DB complexity for zero gain. But to each his own.  My solution above will work fine without changing the `orb_type` relation, so I'll just remove that side note.  The HABTM relation I show above is the self-referential relationship you want.